# Не найден opencv_world452d.dll | C++

Tags: c++, opencv, компоновщик

Написал программу, использующую библиотеку OpenCV. Все настроил, программа пишется, при запуске отладки (F5) в VS 2019 работает прекрасно. Собрал проект, появился .exe файл в Debug папке. А при запуске пишет вот такое:
[image: Ошибка]

С чем это может быть связано? В VS все прекрасно работает, но .exe не хочет. Ошибка линкера? Как ее поправить?

Comment: ¿А указанная библиотека в папке с exe имеется?

Comment: @user7860670 довольно глупая ошибка с моей стороны. Спасибо за ответ)